# How I could create a table model with closure put multiple variable form loop

Tags: groovy, closures

I see this code for how create a table with closure

https://varomorf.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/update-jtable-using-groovy/

but now I need create a table with closure

but using a text title for create all closure variable

like this; this code get the table but using the last value of xbn in this **case 4**

```
 theTable = table(){
        tableModel(){
var1="fecha"
xbn=0
stx="date;product;quant;weight;price".split(";")
println it
while(xbn<4) {
          closureColumn(header:stx[xbn], read:{it[stx[xbn]]})   ;xbn=xbn+1  }



        }
      }
```

normally my code without loop

look like this

```
 theTable = table(){
        tableModel(){
var1="fecha"
xbn=0
stx="date;product;quant;weight;price".split(";")
println it

          closureColumn(header:"date", read:{it["date"]})    
          closureColumn(header:"product", read:{it["product"]})    
              closureColumn(header:"quant", read:{it["quant"]})    
              closureColumn(header:"weight", read:{it["weight"]})    
              closureColumn(header:"price", read:{it["price"]})    

        }
      }
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DSLs don't prevent you from using the regular groovy stuff.  So you can iterate multipl times, but you have to name your closure loop vars (e.g. your outer loop is the `tableModel` and it's implicitly named `it`).

```
...
tableModel() { // it ->
    ...
    "date;product;quant;weight;price".split(";").each { hdr -> // name the loop var
        closureColumn(header:hdr, read:{it[hdr]})    
    }
    ...
}
...
```